# replace outliers with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, data-science

I am trying to clean my data, so I want to handle outliers.

I was able to get the index of each outlier value, but my data contained too many outliers, so I don't want to remove them or replace them with one value "the mean for instance".

I come up with this function, but it seems to have a problem that I can't discover:

```py
def Handle_outliers(df,feature):
    R = df[feature].drop(Outliers(df,feature)).unique()
    df[feature] = df[feature].replace(
        Outliers(df,feature),
        pd.Series( np.random.choice(R, size=len(Outliers(df,feature))) )
        )

    return df[feature]
```

- `R` is a list that should contain all the feature values except for the outliers !!
- and then I want to replace each index that contains an outlier with a random choice from `R`.
- `Outlier` is a function that detects the outliers:

```py
def Outliers(df,feature):
    Q3=df[feature].quantile(0.72)
    Q1=df[feature].quantile(0.28)
    IQR= Q3-Q1
    Lower=Q1-(1.5*IQR)
    Upper=Q3+(1.5*IQR)
    OutLiers_list=df.index[(df[feature]> Upper) | (df[feature] < Lower)]
    return OutLiers_list
```

Would anyone please tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to [`pd.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) should be a list of **values** you want to replace, kind of like a find and replace tool in a text editor. Not a list of **Indicies** like you are currently doing.

You should instead use `.loc` like:

```py
df.loc[Outliers(df,feature), feature] = pd.Series(np.random.choice(R, size=len(Outliers(df,feature))))
```

Comment: `def Handle_outlier(df,feature):
    R=df[feature].drop(Outliers(df,feature)).unique()
    df.loc[Outliers(df,feature), feature] = pd.Series(np.random.choice(R, size=len(Outliers(df,feature))))
    return df[feature]` , still drops the outliers !

Comment: Can you explain what the issue that you're encountering is and what you want to happen?

Comment: sure, I have a task in which I got a dataset that needs to be cleaned, in the phase of handling the outliers, I found out that one feature contains more that more than 1500 outliers, due so I can't drop all these records either can't fill them with only one value like "the mean, for instance, cuz this gonna change the distribution, so I am trying to fill them with a random list from the same feature that contains no outliers.

Comment: I don't know if there is any other approach to handle the situation, I only started data analysis one and half weeks ago, so if there is any other approach tell me